# Overlay of objects is wrong in chrome, but works in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, scroll

I have a question about a project i'm working on.

The website is www.AC-photography.net

When opened in Firefox, the "start scrolling" can be clicked on but when opened in chrome it seems that there is something in front of this layer. Can someone assist on how to make this work in chrome. I will post the html concerning

```
<div id="main">
    <header id="top">
        <div class="color_bar"></div>
    </header>

    <div class="title">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
        <!-- <p class="intro_text"> Alex Cherkasov | Art Director </p>-->
            <a href="#portfolio" class="smoothScroll"><p class="sub_intro">Start Scrolling</p></a>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct problem seems to be z-index: auto on your .title class - set this higher than 800, and it should be fine in Chrome.

That aside, you could also do with cleaning up syntax - a paragraph inside an anchor (block level inside inline), with the second not actually defined as block, is asking for trouble!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's missing a closing `</div>` tag. That might be the problem.